# Finding adjoint of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: exercise]

Tried a variety of approaches, not sure how to do this at all. Stuck on change of basis with this one.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : If $\textsf T$ is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $\textsf V$, $\beta$ is an *orthonormal* basis for $\textsf V$ and $A$ is the matrix that represents $\textsf T$ in the ordered basis $\beta$, then $A^*$ (the conjugate transpose of $A$) is the matrix that represents $\textsf T^*$ in the same basis.

Comment: Why does β have to be an orthonormal basis?